# Getting Page Number of PDF document from Adobe Reader's ActiveX control

Tags: delphi, activex, delphi-7, adobe-reader

I'm successfully using Delph 7 and the ActiveX control of Adobe Reader version 7 to extract the page number from an open PDF document housed in the ActiveX component (TAcroPDF). I am interested in upgrading to the latest Adobe reader but something changed in Adobe Reader 8 (and 9) that prevented me from upgrading (I have not tested Adobe 10/X). With Adobe 7, I use the Windows SDK function EnumChildWindows to gather the child windows of my form containing the TAcroPDF component and find a control with the name AVPageNumView, then FindWindowEx to get its handle. Then I call SendMessage to get the text of that control which has the page number information. With Adobe 8 and 9, window/control AVPageNumView is no longer there it seems. Thus I am stuck in Adobe 7 and still looking for a way to get the page number, preferably Adobe 9 or 10/X. The goal would be to not have to do a complete rewrite with another technology, but I am open to that if its the only solution.

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

You're using a wndclass name (`AVPageNumView`). Obviously, the class name has changed in the new version. You can use something like [WinDowse](http://www.greatis.com/delphicb/windowse/) to investigate the windows in the newer version of Reader to find out the new class names. Update your code to first check for the old wndclass; if it's not found, try and find the new one.

Answer (score 0):

```
function EnumWindowProc(pHwnd: THandle; Edit: Integer): LongBool; stdcall;
    function GetWindowTxt(gwtHwnd: THandle): string;
    var dWTextBuf: PChar;
        TextLen: Integer;
    begin
      TextLen := SendMessage(gwtHwnd, WM_GetTextLength, 0, 0);;
      dWTextBuf := StrAlloc(TextLen + 1);
      SendMessage(gwtHwnd, WM_GetText, TextLen + 1, Integer(dWTextBuf));
      Result := dWTextBuf;
      StrDispose(dWTextBuf);
    end;

    function GetClassNameTxt(gcnHwnd: THandle): string;
    var dWClassBuf: PChar;
    begin
      dWClassBuf := StrAlloc(1024);
      GetClassName(gcnHwnd, dWClassBuf, 1024);
      Result := dWClassBuf;
      StrDispose(dWClassBuf);
    end;

begin
  Result := LongBool(True);
  if (GetClassNameTxt(pHwnd) = 'AVL_AVView') and (GetWindowTxt(pHwnd) = 'AVPageView') then
  begin
    TEdit(Edit).Text :=  GetWindowTxt(FindWindowEx(pHwnd, 0, 'RICHEDIT50W', nil));
    Result := LongBool(False);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EnumChildWindows(AcroPDF1.Handle, @EnumWindowProc, LongInt(Edit1));
end;
```